# Repeated printing of message after multiple input with fgetc(stdin)

Tags: c, input, stdin, fgetc

I'm writing a program that has 2 functionnalities. When he opens the program, the user is asked to choose one by entering either 1 or 2 as an input. If the user enters something wrong, he will be asked to enter its choice again.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char c;

int main() {
    printf("What do you wish to do ?\nEnter 1 to convert raw PCM to WAV \nEnter 2 to convert WAV to raw PCM \nChoice : ");
    c = fgetc(stdin);
    while(c != '1' && c != '2') {
        printf("You specified an incorrect input\nEnter 1 to convert raw PCM to WAV\nEnter 2 to convert WAV to raw PCM\nChoice : ");
        c = fgetc(stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

I tested this "incorrect input" case by entering 78 as the input, but here is the console output :

```
What do you wish to do ?
Enter 1 to convert WAV to raw PCM
Enter 2 to convert raw PCM to WAV
Choice : 78
You specified an incorrect input
Enter 1 to convert raw PCM to WAV
Enter 2 to convert WAV to raw PCM
Choice : You specified an incorrect input
Enter 1 to convert raw PCM to WAV
Enter 2 to convert WAV to raw PCM
Choice : You specified an incorrect input
Enter 1 to convert raw PCM to WAV
Enter 2 to convert WAV to raw PCM
Choice :
```

It displays the "incorrect input" message three times in a row before asking for further input.
What could be the cause of this repetition ?
*Note : the same thing happens if I use getchar() instead of fgetc(stdin).*

Comment: Two issues: The `Enter` key you press will be added to the input buffer as a newline, which you don't handle; The second is that [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an **`int`**, which is important for the `EOF` check you're missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input `78<Enter>` is added to the input as the three separate characters `'7'`, `'8'` and `'\n'`. That's why you get the invalid input message thrice.

My suggestion is that you stop using characters, and instead read the whole line as a single string, and then attempt to parse it as an integer instead. Perhaps something like

```
// Input validation loop
for (;;)
{
    // Print prompt
    printf("What do you wish to do ?\nEnter 1 to convert raw PCM to WAV \nEnter 2 to convert WAV to raw PCM \nChoice : ");

    // Read the whole next line as input
    char input[256];
    if (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin) == NULL)
    {
        // TODO: Input error, handle it accordingly
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Parse the input
    unsigned choice;
    if (sscanf(input, "%u", &choice) != 1)
    {
        printf("Input was not a number\n");
        continue;
    }

    // See if the input was valid
    if (choice != 1 && choice != 2)
    {
        printf("Input was not a valid choice, please try again\n");
        continue;
    }

    // By this point the input and its validation was successful,
    // don't loop anymore
    break;
}
```